# Sublime Text Sidebar Highlighting Changed Row

Tags: java, github, sublimetext3, sidebar

After working on some javascript and installing some packages (Babel, Emmet, JsPrettier, Sublime Linter, Sublime Linter-eslint) and experimenting with Github, the row that I changed gets a yellow highlight on the side bar. This happens even for code (even other languages like Java) that I never used github with, which is frustrating.

Does anyone know how to disable this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

The yellow highlighting in the sidebar (it's not actually sidebar, it's called the gutter region) is an example of the [incremental diff](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/incremental_diff.html) functionality of Sublime Text, which is used to track modifications done to a file. To disable that, you can to go to command palette (using <kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd>) & then type `Preferences: Settings`. In the right hand side of the newly opened window, you'd need to add `mini_diff: false`. That should disable showing all those highlights in the gutter.